# Identify Query Activities within Automation using ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I am trying to identify all the activity queries within an automation using ssjs. I came up with the following code but it seems not working rightnow. Have you guys ever had this problem? Did you solve it somehow? Thanks in advance for your help. What am I missing?
Here is my code:

````
var cols1 = ['ObjectID'];
var Program = api.retrieve('Automation', cols1, { Property : 'CustomerKey', SimpleOperator : 'equals', Value : 'xxxxxxx' });
var objectid = Program.Results[0].ObjectID;

var cols2 = ['ObjectID','Name','Automation','CustomerKey'];
var Activity = api.retrieve('AutomationActivity', cols2, { Property : 'Automation.ObjectID', SimpleOperator : 'equals', Value : objectid }); ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/372527/edit) your question to add additional information: *how* it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text, *exactly* how it is behaving differently than expected). *(Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center where, among other things, it says that your question should include, 'A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')*

Comment: The API work with Automations is complicated.  I'd suggest reviewing Ivan Razine's blog post on this topic: [How to use WSProxy to work with Automations in server-side JavaScript](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-automations-in-server-side-javascript/)

Comment: Also, as @Moonpie suggested, please take the time to provide _everything_ needed for someone else to replicate your issue.  That includes the full code and exact error messages.  This community is very helpful, but there's not much to go on here.